# VS2010 devenv.exe.config issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, configuration-files

I am unable to open vs2010 .I have windows 7 OS and it is 32 bit machine. Event log says

***Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 
 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.Config" on line 13. Invalid Xml syntax.***

devenv.exe.config file got corrupted lot of junk characters i do not know how it got corrupted.Reset my config setting will be my last option.I do not have any back up of the file

I tried to fix my self i know it is a bad idea.After fixing the file I am not able to save the file. I tried to find out any process has locked the file using Procmon.exe and using another software called unlockit .There is no process locked this config file.

Is there a way to regenerate the config file with out resetting it ?

Answer (score 1):

The only option I can think is to create a copy of your devenv.exe.config, then regenerate the devenv.exe.config and paste the additional settings from your copy into the regenerated devenv.exe.config.

You should consider installing a backup application and regularly backing up your development machine. This will allow you to restore individual files or recover your hard disk in the event of a failure. It really is a time saver when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix file with a Text Editor running as a Administrator (not windows user account, administrator for program).

Answer (score 0):

Open notepad as Administrator.
Open devenv.exe.config in notepad, make changes
And Save it in same location.

It worked for me for machine.config.